# Where is __USE_BSD flag defined?

Tags: c++, linux

My project is building to Debian 8 without any problems.

But when building on debian 10, it leaves for this block:

```
#if (defined __USE_BSD)
....
#else
#error "this condition is met"
#endif
```

Where should __USE_BSD flag be defined?

Why is building to 8, but not 10?

Comment: If it's your project, as you say, you would have presumably identified the conditions in which that macro would be expected to be defined.  Given that it is a reserved identifier (i.e.  reserved for use by the implementation) the place to look would be in documentation for the particular compilers used to build your project under Debian 8 and Debian 10.

Comment: `grep` works nicely for searching files for strings, I suggest applying it to the directories holding your project and the system header files.

Comment: The fact is that there is no definition in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__USE_BSD` is [deprecated](https://lwn.net/Articles/590381/). It has changed to `__USE_MISC` and it is defined in `features.h` from **glibc**. You can see it in issues on [github](https://github.com/dalmatinerdb/mmath/pull/30) and on [LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/590381/). From Debian 8 to Debian 10 the glic package has changed to adapt to this situation, so you have to verify for the definition of `__USE_MISC`
. 
Code below:

```
#include <features.h>

#if (defined __USE_MISC)
...
#else
 #error "this condition is met"
#endif
```